# How to get return result from Paypal button created using button factory

Tags: php, paypal

I created one paypal button using button factory and used provided html code in php file, I provided urls for cancel/return and success.

Now i would like to get value in session or request from paypal to catch whether its successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use the url through which the user came back (i.e. cancel, return, success) to detect whether the transaction succeeded, this is not a very secure method. You best save the result which PayPal posts back to your secret link in your database (assuming you have one) and check that on the users next request. You can then insert the value from your database into your session. 
If you registered the beginning of a PayPal transaction while PayPal didn't return a result yet and the user did do a request, you might for example show a page telling the user to finish its transaction before coming back to your site.

Comment: how do i get user email etc in POST back data

Comment: I think it depends on which PayPal service you are using, but you can set several variables when you post to PayPal. All these variables will be set in the PayPal response too. I think it's best if you have a look at the documentation for the details.

Comment: i already mentioned , i am using classic paypal button factory